# Issue regarding the use of Ontology in python code

Tags: nlp, ontology, semantic-analysis

I've worked on a project related to the NLP. I built an ontology for that but I don't know to exploit it in my code.
Would you mind giving me some tips or indicates regarding the use/extract meaningful information from the ontology inside the python code?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you need an ontology for in the first place?

Comment: I wanna extract information from it and compare it with text piece. For semantic purposes.